# Django forms.py not getting updated with new values from DB

Tags: python, django, forms

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    template = models.BooleanField("Is Template",default=False)

    @staticmethod
    def template_as_tuple():
        return Test.objects.filter(template=True).values_list('id','name')
```

forms.py

```
class Test2(forms.ModelForm):
    templates = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Catalogue.predefined_settings_as_tuple(), required=False)
    path = orms.FileField()
```

The problem is when i add templates in the models it is not shown in the forms.py. I need to restart the webserver for the updates to be shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of that staticmethod. Do this in the form instead:

```
class Test2(forms.ModelForm):
    templates = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Test.objects.filter(template=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel's answer is correct, but if you will be filtering the objects often, a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) might be more appropriate:

```
class TemplateFilter(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(TemplateFilter, self).get_query_set().filter(template=True)

class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    slug_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    template = models.BooleanField("Is Template",default=False)

    objects = models.Manager()
    templates = TemplateFilter()

class Test2(forms.ModelForm):
    templates = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Test.templates.all())
```